# org-display-inline-images an remote image

Tags: emacs, org-mode, tramp

I have an image on a remote machine that I want to display inline in an org file.
But the image displayed is a black square.

-------My Org file --------

`[[file:/ssh:user@host:/path/to/image.png]]`

----------Error message -------

> 1 images displayed inline
>
> ImageMagick error: no decode delegate for this image format `/ssh:user@host:/path/to/image.png' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552

I suppose org-display-inline-images does not recognize the link indicates a remote file and tries to evaluate the path locally.  How can I make it recognize the remote path and perhaps use tramp to download the file and then display it?

Comment: Can you view a *.png image in an Emacs buffer all by itself without using org-mode?  On a Windows machine (for example), a square will appear if the *.dll file for *.png images is wrong.

Comment: If I click the link I can see the image.  Also if the file is local, inline display works fine.  My problem here is that it does not work with tramp when the file is on a remote machine.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? It does not look like orgmode support opening images from ssh